# android openfilechooser not showing voice recorder for android version less than 3.0

Tags: android

i want to upload a  file in webview. when i clicked on choose button for devices having android version above 3.0 are not showing voice recorder option in chooser. 
here's my code

```
public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {

        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File file = new File(path, "temp.jpg");
        file.delete();
        mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;  
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        i.setType("*/*");
        Intent openInChooser=Intent.createChooser(i,"File Chooser");
        Intent value[]=new Intent[2];
        value[0]= new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        value[0].addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

        Intent fileExplorer= new Intent(MainActivity.this,DirectoryBrowser.class);
        fileExplorer.setComponent(new ComponentName(MainActivity.this, DirectoryBrowser.class));
        value[1] = new LabeledIntent(fileExplorer, "com.app.insta7", "File Explorer", R.drawable.folder);
        openInChooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, value);
        MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(openInChooser, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
    }
```

if i add this line and increased intent array size to 3

```
value[2] = new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
```

for devices version less than 3.0 chooser is showing option twice.kindly suggest solution to this problem if you have any.

Answer (score 0):

This annoyingly undocumented function has changed prototype a couple of times. We use this code when we want to support file uploading:

```
// For Android 4.1+
public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadFileCallback, String acceptType, String capture) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Opening file chooser for type '" + acceptType + "', capture '" + capture + "'");
    // Add your file picker code here!
}

// For Android 3.0+
public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadFileCallback, String acceptType) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Opening legacy file chooser for type '" + acceptType + "'");
    openFileChooser(uploadFileCallback, acceptType, "");
}

// For Android < 3.0
public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadFileCallback) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Opening very legacy file chooser");
    openFileChooser(uploadFileCallback, "");
}
```